# Disallow creation of new records in joined datasource when "master" has no records

Tags: join, datasource, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, morph-x

I have following problem in AX

**Background:**

- two tables A and B, relation A:B is 1:N, B contains reference to A.recId
- dataSource B joins dataSource A using Active join
- both datasources are displayed in their own grids (records displayed in grid B are related to record selected in grid A)

**Desired behavior:**

- I want to prohibit creation of new records in B if there are no records selected or existing in A, because otherwise I won't have the relation created correctly

I assume I can put code responsible for it into init() method of dataSource B and active method of dataSource A, but isn't there a way to achieve this behavior more elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

`InnerJoin` relation type should do the work ¿Have you tried that?

If this doesn't work please specify your AX version.

Comment: I'll try it and let you know, but I guess that if I use inner join, it takes all records from A and displays all related records from B in grid for B. Guess this is whole point of Active join, that it displays joined records only for actively selected records in master datasource. I am using AX 2012